# Regex para validar moeda, fracionada, aceitando negativos

Tags: regex, delphi-10, valor-monetário

Irei utilizar em Delphi 10.1. Consegui chegar na expressão abaixo, mas por falta de conhecimento e prática, não estou conseguindo chegar até onde desejo.

Regex:

```
^(^[\-]?[1-9]|0)(?:[0-9]{0,10}|0)(?:,\d{0,2})?$
```

Preciso analisar se o número é um valor monetário válido, que sejam apenas números, sem espaço, sem separador de milhar ou símbolo de moeda, possua nenhuma, uma ou até 2 casas decimais, e que aceite positivos (sem sinal de +) e negativos (precedidos por -), aceitando zero se for o único número, mas não zero no início se for inteiro ou fracionado, mas que aceite zero no início se o zero for o único anterior à vírgula e a parte fracionada for maior que um centavo.

Deverá aceitar:

```
0
0,//Será formatado após
0,0
0,00
0,01 até 0,99
0,1
1234567890,99
-1234567890,99
-0,01 até -0,99
1,00
-1,00
```

Não poderá aceitar:

```
-0
-0,
-0,00
-,01 a -,99
//Sequencia vazio
01,00
01
0012
```

Comment: Consegui chegar na abaixo, que permite negativo ou positivo, mas não permite zero no início. Sei que não parece 100% correta, mas parece próxima. Por enquanto só falta permitir 0,01 até 0,99. já -0,00 desisti por enquanto. Até agora: ^(^[\-]?[1-9]|^[^0]?[1-9])(?:[0-9]{0,10}|0)(?:,\d{0,2})?$

Answer (score 1):

Dá para simplificar os critérios.

Se o primeiro dígito for zero, não pode ter sinal antes, e depois dele pode ter só a vírgula, ou a vírgula seguida de 1 ou 2 dígitos (os casos `0,0`, `0,00`, `0,01` até `0,99` e `0,1` no fundo são variações desta regra). Então todos estes casos são cobertos por `0(,\d{0,2})?`:

- o trecho `\d{0,2}` significa "de zero a 2 dígitos" (repare que não precisa diferenciar se algum deles é zero ou não; tanto faz, já que você aceita tanto `0,0` quanto `0,00`, `0,1` e `0,01` até `0,99`). O caso de "zero dígitos" é para aceitar somente a vírgula.
- todo o trecho "vírgula seguida de `\d{0,2}` é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), portanto também aceita somente `0`

Quando o primeiro dígito não é zero, aí pode ter o sinal de menos, mas não pode ter a vírgula sozinha (tem que ter um ou 2 dígitos depois dela). Então este trecho fica `-?[1-9]\d*(,\d{1,2})?`:

- `-?` indica que o sinal de menos é opcional
- `[1-9]` é um dígito de 1 a 9
- `\d*` é "zero ou mais dígitos". Se quiser limitar a quantidade, pode usar algo como `\d{0,9}` (mínimo zero, máximo 9 dígitos). O importante é que o mínimo seja zero dígitos para que a regex aceite números com apenas um dígito (que será correpondente ao trecho `[1-9]`)
- `(,\d{1,2})?` - vírgula seguida de 1 ou 2 dígitos, e todo este trecho é opcional (ou tem vírgula com 1 ou 2 casas decimais, ou não tem nada)

Se começar com `-0`, é obrigatório ter vírgula e as casas decimais não podem ser somente zero. Então ficaria `-0,(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?)`:

- `-0,` - essa parte é obrigatória (sinal de menos, zero, vírgula)
- depois temos uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou"), com 2 opções:

  - `0[1-9]` - o número zero seguido de um dígito de 1 a 9
  - `[1-9]\d?` - um dígito de 1 a 9 seguido opcionalmente por um dígito (assim ele pega `-0,4`, `-0,40` e `-0,42`)

Juntando as 3 opções, ficamos com:

```
^(0(,\d{0,2})?|-?[1-9]\d*(,\d{1,2})?|-0,(0[1-9]|[1-9]\d?))$
```

Eu coloco as 3 opções acima em outra alternância, assim a regex tenta uma, se não der, tenta outra, etc. Também coloco em volta da expressão os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e fim da string. Assim ela garante que a string só pode ter o que está na regex.

O detalhe da alternância é que ela verifica as opções da esquerda para a direita. Ou seja, primeiro ela vê se começa com zero. Se não, vê se começa com o hífen opcional e depois tem um dígito de 1 a 9. Senão, vê se tem o hífen e um zero depois.

Assim, cada caso é verificado separadamente, sem risco de falsos positivos, e sem misturar as regras (como estava acontecendo com sua regex, que tentou fazer tudo de uma vez).

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/317841/112052) se esqueceu de limitar a 2 casas decimais, além de usar [*lookaheads* negativos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que apesar de úteis, eu não achei necessários aqui (além disso, eles deixam a regex mais lenta, já que a função deles é voltar e verificar o que tem antes - veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/i9LqGB/2/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/RnImtV/4) um comparativo do desempenho, a quantidade de passos necessários é cerca de 6 vezes menor, além da expressão ter ficado um pouco menos confusa - mas ainda sim não é tão simples de ler, entender e manter, na minha opinião).

Answer (score 0):

**Existem 3 regras que você deve considerar com o seu problema:**

- Não pode capturar se é negativo e iniciado em ",";
- Não pode capturar se o número é iniciado em "0" e não tem "," em seguida;
- Não pode capturar um número negativo que não possui pelo menos um número de 1 a 9 na sequencia de caracteres.

**Então para cubrir todas as possibilidades devem ser capturados apenas**

- Números positivos que iniciam em 0 e tem casas decimais logo em seguida do 0;
- Negativos que iniciam em 0, porém possuem pelo menos um número entre 1 e 9 na sequencia de caracteres (indicando que não é somente um 0 negativo);
- Números que são iniciados entre 1 e 9 e podem conter parte decimal;
- números negativos iniciados em 1 ou 9 que podem ou não conter casas decimais;
- Número 0 que não tem o caracter "-" antes mas pode conter um caracter "," após o "0"; em seguida;

Para isso fiz essa regex:

```
(?<!-)(0,\d*[0-9])|(?<!0)([1-9]\d*,\d*)|(-[0-9],\d*?[1-9]\d*)|(-[1-9]\d*,{0,1}\d*)|\b(?<!-)(0)[a-zA-Z,\n]
```

Cada grupo de captura representa uma dessas possibilidades. 
[Você pode ver essa regex rodando e o seu resultado nesse link](https://regex101.com/r/RnImtV/3).